# How to use camel send batch http request?

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, soa, esb, eip

I have 1,000,000 IDs, and need to call a REST API once per day for each user. How can I use Camel to send batch HTTP requests?

My current solution is to create an HTTP component for every ID, using Quartz. But It will create 1,000,000 Quartz jobs, the performance is bad.

I have two ideas:

1. If Camel can provide a batch API, I could use that to send 1,000,000
   requests to the same URL but with different parameters. That is one
   Quartz job. Does Camel support that API?
2. Every HTTP request only visit one time, and use spring schedule to
   control. But for each request Camel will poll the server. How can I
   make Camel only call the REST API once?

The codes here:

```
// ids is a List, contains 1,000,000 id
for (final String id : ids) {
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from(String.format("quartz://%s/?cron=0+0+12+*+*+?", id))
            .to(String.format("http:xxx.com?id=%s", id))
            .to("file:to");
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could more heave to create million routes for sending the request with different id.
with the help of [bean](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html), you can define the loop of sending the request in the bean method.

BTW, you can change the id with message header "CamelHttpQuery".

Comment: any example? your mean is change the id with message header "CamelHttpQuery" can aggregate multiple request to a single one?